# Pass additional parameters to ActiveScaffold view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I'm using ActiveScaffold in a Rails 3 project. I have a layout which yields the default AS views, configured the following way:

layouts/admin.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => "layouts/admin_header" %>
[some html]
<%= yield %>
[more html]
<%= render :partial => "layouts/admin_footer" %>
```

I then use a BaseController, which renders this layout

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  [some global settings / restrictions]
  layout "admin"
end
```

Now, In my model-specific controller, I just use:

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController

  active_scaffold :user do |config|
    config.columns[:id].label = "#"
    [more config]
  end

  def conditions_for_collection
    [setting some conditions]
  end
end
```

Thats all working fine. Now what I would like to do is pass and display a param to the layouts/admin view.

Usually it would be sufficient to set an instance variable in the controller action `@my_var = params[:some_param]`, but the controller action is inside AS. If I set it somewhere else, it wont be passed to the view. So I tried implementing the controller action (I want to change the display for the user list action):

```
def list
  @my_var = "test"
  render :active_scaffold => "users"
end
```

I was hoping to be able to tell AS to use it's default view to render the list with `render :active_scaffold => "users"`, but unfortunately that doesn't work, I'm getting

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate
Missing template admin/users/index, admin/base/index, application/index, active_scaffold_overrides/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}
```

If I leave out the render call, I'm getting the same result. So my question is: how can I either pass a param without overwriting the controller method, or instruct AS to use the default view in my controller action?

Answer (score 0):

It's rather simple, if you find the proper [doc page](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/Custom-respond_to):

```
def list_respond_to_html
  @my_var = "test"
  render :action => :list
end
```

By default, ActiveScaffold responds to html, json, js, xml, and yaml mime. The method format is `<action>_respond_to_<format>`